# How to trigger a callback function when a button is pressed for a long time

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can I create a callback for a long-time-pressed button? For example, I want to save a new value when I press a button for more than 2 seconds. Is there any good way to do this?

```
b3=tkinter.Button(frames, text='1',font='Agency 50', relief='groove',bd=5,width= 3, height=1)
b3.bind("<Button-1>", savep1)
b3.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",savep11)



def savep1(event):
dur()    
if duration > 2:
    update1()
    clock[0]=time.time()
else:
    connection=sqlite3.connect('joimax.db')
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Speicherplatz WHERE name='save1'"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    for dsatz in cursor:
        scv.set(str(dsatz[2]))
        direction.set(dsatz[1])
        connection.close()
        grafik()
        print(' speed: ', str(dsatz[2]))
```

Just like I said, I tried to judge the duration of two actions. But there are always errors.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\Übung\gui4.py", line 147, in savep1
    if duration > 2:
NameError: name 'duration' is not defined
```

**Update**: I solved the problem yesterday. Just use the `after`, and here is the code. It causes a little bit slow down of the skript, but better than nothing.

```
def loop1():

    global duration
    if duration>2:
        duration=0
        update1()
    else:
        if press==False:
            duration=0
            do1()
        else:
            print('loop', duration)

            duration=duration+timeit.timeit()+0.25
            main.after(250, loop1)

def savep1(event):
    global press
    press=True
    main.after(0,loop1)

def savep11(event):
    global press
    press=False
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about how your functions work but here's a quick example I made that should illustrate a way you could do this.

The first function will call `time.clock()` and store it as a global value (so that the second function can access it). This function is called when the button is first clicked.

The second function will call `time.clock()` and calculate the difference between this and the initial time.

If this time is greater than 2.0 I call a third function; this could be where you "save your new value". I just used this to show that it will only be done at times >= 2.0 seconds

If the time is less than 2 seconds I simply print a message with the time.

Here's the example code, hope it will help you solve your problem.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import time

root = Tk()
startTime = 0

def doStuff():

    global startTime
    startTime = time.clock()

def doMore():

    total = time.clock() - startTime
    if total >= 2.0:
        doEvenMore(total)
    else:
        print("Sorry, only %5f seconds." %total)

def doEvenMore(total):

    # This will be whatever you do after 2 seconds (save new value)
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Congrats", "You held a button down for %.5f seconds!" %total)

b = Button(root, text = "Try Me", justify = CENTER)
b.pack()
# Button down: get a start time
b.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: doStuff())
# Button up: get end time, check if you do the function or not
b.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: doMore())

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, for your help thanks a lot, I didn't try your idea but I guess it works well. The only flaw is that you can only show the Messagebox after release the Button. Actually I solved it yesterday, just take the advantage of `after`.